# What is this verb form - 通れ

Tags: verbs

This is an example from [the Progressive Japanese-English Dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/49868/m1u/%E6%9F%84/):

> 彼は短刀を柄{つか}も**通れ**と男の胸に突き刺した
>   He thrust his dagger home [up to the hilt] into the man's chest.

What is the grammar behind this verb form of 通る? Is this a fixed expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [彼]{かれ}は[短刀]{たんとう}を[柄]{つか}も[通]{とお}れと[男]{おとこ}の[胸]{むね}に[突]{つ}き[刺]{さ}した。

in meaning, is equal to:

> 彼は短刀を『柄も通れ！』と男の胸に突き刺した。

「通れ」 is the [命令形]{めいれいけい} (imperative form) the of the verb 「通る」.

「柄も通れ」 is what the guy thought to himself as he stabbed the other guy.  He wanted to stab deep. = "Let even the hilt go through!"

This is no fixed expression, but you will keep seeing the structure:

> 「Verb A in imperative + と + Verb phrase B」=
>
> "(Someone) did (Verb B) thinking/saying/praying, etc. 'Let (Verb A) happen!'"

Needless to say, 「と」 is the quotative particle.